# How do you automatically assign values to an array based on the position in the array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.
I'm trying to create an array like this, with 52 entries, which I'll later graph.

`p = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1....]`

It is used to model demand over the year, and these values will be coefficients later on. I want to use 0.1 for slow periods like the summer or Easter, but in the model I'd like to be able to automatically assign the smaller value for certain positions in the array without typing it out manually over 52 positions. Can I somehow define the value of the array where it will be 1 for weeks 0 to 26, 0.1 for weeks 27-30 and then back to 1? Ideally with the possibility of easily changing the coefficient and the weeks defined as "holiday"?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably better to assign values at specific slices:

```
x = [1] * 52 # initialized everything to 1
x[:27] = [1] * 26 # 0-26, not needed
x[27:31] = [0.1] * 4 # 27-30

print(x) # [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```